# Failed processing pyformat-parameters; %s" % err

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have the following query in a script:

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    connect = conn.cursor()
    params = {'build': self.tc.tag, 'page': self, 'object_id': self.object_id, 'page_header': self.page_header,
              'interval': t.interval, 'timestamp': timestamp}
    query = u'INSERT INTO page_load_times (build, page, object_id, page_header, elapsed_time, date_run) ' \
            'VALUES (%(build)s, %(page)s, %(object_id)s, %(page_header)s, %(interval)s, %(timestamp)s)'
    connect.execute(query, params)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

When I run this, it is getting the following error from the `'page': self` parameter:

```
"Failed processing pyformat-parameters; %s" % err)
ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'appmainmenu' 
cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

`self` is only returning a unicode string. I added `'charset': 'utf8', 'use_unicode': True` to my config for the connection and that did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the params dictionary I cast `self` as unicode so now it looks like so `unicode(self)`